# TFS 2010 Build Automation for a Web Site: Delete a file in the publish folder after build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

We are trying to adapt a build automation strategy for our ASP.NET web site (not a web project) in vs 2010 ultimate & tfs 2010.

Build definition makes the build and publishes the web site into folders like

<drop_folder>\<defn_name>\<defn_name>_<year><month><day>.<build no>\Release_PublishedWebsites

Now we try to delete particular files and folders from that folder. For instance the "images" or "files" folders, that we need to exclude before packaging. I know that if it were a web project, there exists a straightforward solution. We also tried to modify the build process template (xaml) file. There is a "DeleteDirectory" component but we couldn't figure out what to write to the Directory variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the XAML way, you would just have to feed the `Directory` argument of `DeleteDirectory` with the physical UNC path to the folder you 're trying to get rid of.
Something along the lines of 
`String.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\Release_PublishedWebsites", BuildDetail.DropLocation, BuildDetail.BuildNumber, Date.Now.Year)`
should get you near to your target.
 Since the drop location of the build might be on a different machine, also ensure that the account conducting the build (by default = NetworkService) has the rights to delete folders on the target.

Comment: Thank you so much. Following your hint, we were able to find what we are looking for. It is actually simpler than I thought: BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\\Release\\_PublishedWebsites\\" is what you need at all.